# SVG image not displaying in mozilla firefox

Tags: svg, angular7

I am using Angular7 and trying to load SVG image as an Object element. when I do ng serve and open the URL in firefox its not loading svg file. In chrome its working perfectly fine. and If I open the svg file directly(not through the angular application) in firefox it is loading.

I have tried viewbox and height & width and all but still same problem.

```
<object id="svg1" data="assets/12455_01.svg" type="image/svg+xml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></object>
```

inside my svg root element I have viewbox as: viewBox="-36.52 -2607.7 2723 2621"

```
css file:
object{
    width:100%;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

I want to display the svg file provided in Object element when I load/run the application in all kinds of browsers.

Comment: Can you open the svg file in FireFox?

Comment: have you tried giving absolute path of the image instead of relative path? may be it is an issue with your path?

Comment: path shouldn't be a problem. Because, I am able to access using chrome.
@enxaneta, Yes. If I open directly the .svg file I am able to see the image in firefox. But only problem is through Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed myself, but not sure whether this is correct approach. I have set the path and type through ngOnInit like below and it got loaded successfully.

```
ngOnInit(){
let obj = document.getElementById("svg1");
    obj.setAttribute('data', this.svgPath);
    obj.setAttribute('type', "image/svg+xml");
}
```